# Truth Tables with implies operator

Tags: logic

Is my information correct here?

[image]

In order it to be a tautology it has to be all true values right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For it to be a tautology, you would need $T$ in all four positions in the last column.  The table as given is not correct.  In the bottom two lines, $\sim p$ is true, so the implication is true, regardless of he antecedent.  The top line still makes it not a tautology.

Comment: so the last two are true sir?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Tautology is a statement which is always true.